# Conditional RedirectToAction in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just wondering where, in MVC, the responsibility for determining where to redirect belongs. I *think* it's the controller, but I'm not sure.

In the Create action of a `WorkshopItem` I'm creating a new WorkshopItem from the ViewModel passed in, then saving it to the database. Part of the ViewModel is a `SelectedCustomerId` and `CustomerName`, if the SelectedCustomerId is empty and the name is empty I get the `default customer` entity and associate it with the item. If the Id is empty but the name is not then the user has searched for a customer but no matches were found, so I take the value and create a new customer record and attach it.

```
[NHibernateActionFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(WorkshopItemCreateViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Customer customer = null;

        if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() && 
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName))
            customer = CreateNewCustomer(model.CustomerName);
        else if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName))
        {
            // Assign the System Valued customer if no customer was selected.
            var id = Guid.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValuedCustomerId"]);
            customer = Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                              .Where(c => c.Id == id)
                              .SingleOrDefault();
        }

        // other stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

This is working fine, but now I want to also `RedirectToAction` depending on whether a customer record was created or not because if a customer was created it only has a `Name` and I'd like to redirect to the Edit action on the Customer Controller passing the CustomerId (which I think I can do). My question is really whether this is valid to do in MVC or should this be a responsibility elsewhere?

This would look like this:

```
[NHibernateActionFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(WorkshopItemCreateViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Customer customer = null;
        bool newCustomer = false;
        if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() && 
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName))
        {
            customer = CreateNewCustomer(model.CustomerName);
            newCustomer = true;
        }
        else if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName))
        {
            // Assign the System Valued customer if no customer was selected.
            var id = Guid.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValuedCustomerId"]);
            customer = Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                              .Where(c => c.Id == id)
                              .SingleOrDefault();
        }

        // other stuff
        if (newCustomer)
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Customer", new {id=customer.Id});
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, the controller maintains responsibility of returning content and redirecting to the appropriate actions.  You can think of the controller as almost a traffic cop, directing things where to go and sending the right stuff to the appropriate places. An example from your code above might look something like this:

```
if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName))
    customer = CreateNewCustomer(model.CustomerName);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = customer.Id});
else if (model.SelectedCustomerId == new Guid() && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CustomerName)){
    // Assign the System Valued customer if no customer was selected.
    var id = Guid.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValuedCustomerId"]);
    customer = Session.QueryOver<Customer>().Where(c => c.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
    return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherMethod");

    }    
        // other stuff
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```